# error flattening (convert to data.frame) XML file in R using xlm2 and xlmtools

Tags: r, xml2, xlm

I am trying to convert this [xml_file](https://www.camara.leg.br/SitCamaraWS/Deputados.asmx/ObterDetalhesDeputado?ideCadastro=141428&numLegislatura=) (and many other similar ones) to a data.frame in R. Desired outcome: a data.frame (or tibble, data.table, etc) with:

- One row per `Deputado` (which is the main tag/level of `xml_file`, there are 4 of those)
- All variables within each Deputado should be columns.
- Neste categories with multiple values (such as `comissao`, `cargoComissoes`, etc) can be ignored.

In the code below, I tried to  follow [Example 2 in the readme of github/.../xmltools](https://github.com/dantonnoriega/xmltools#example-2) closely, but I got the error:

```
...
+   dplyr::mutate_all(empty_as_na)
Error: Argument 4 must be length 4, not 39
```

Any help fixing this (or different strategy with complete example) would be greatly appreciated.

The code (with reproducible error) is:

```
file <- "https://www.camara.leg.br/SitCamaraWS/Deputados.asmx/ObterDetalhesDeputado?ideCadastro=141428&numLegislatura="
doc <- file %>%
  xml2::read_xml()
nodeset <- doc %>%
  xml2::xml_children()
length(nodeset) # lots of nodes!
nodeset[1] %>% # lets look at ONE node's tree
  xml_view_tree()
# lets assume that most nodes share the same structure
terminal_paths <- nodeset[1] %>%
  xml_get_paths(only_terminal_parent = TRUE)

terminal_xpaths <- terminal_paths %>% ## collapse xpaths to unique only
  unlist() %>%
  unique()

# xml_to_df (XML package based)
## note that we use file, not doc, hence is_xml = FALSE
# df1 <- lapply(xpaths, xml_to_df, file = file, is_xml = FALSE, dig = FALSE) %>%
#   dplyr::bind_cols()
# df1

# xml_dig_df (xml2 package based)
## faster!
empty_as_na <- function(x){
  if("factor" %in% class(x)) x <- as.character(x) ## since ifelse wont work with factors
  if(class(x) == "character") ifelse(as.character(x)!="", x, NA) else x
}

terminal_nodesets <- lapply(terminal_xpaths, xml2::xml_find_all, x = doc) # use xml docs, not nodesets! I think this is because it searches the 'root'.
df2 <- terminal_nodesets %>%
  purrr::map(xml_dig_df) %>%
  purrr::map(dplyr::bind_rows) %>%
  dplyr::bind_cols() %>%
  dplyr::mutate_all(empty_as_na)
```

Comment: Does the example work for you? If gives me an error in the `bind_cols` step here `terminal_nodesets %>%
  purrr::map(xml_dig_df) %>%
  purrr::map(dplyr::bind_rows) %>%
  dplyr::bind_cols() ` stating `Error: Argument 4 must be length 4, not 39`. The list of dataframes are of unequal length hence it is not able to `cbind` them.

Comment: @RonakShah, that is the same error that I get. The only adaptation I did in the code above was to change the xml file in the first line. If you want run the original example just change it to `file <- "http://aiweb.cs.washington.edu/research/projects/xmltk/xmldata/data/courses/wsu.xml"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with XML package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(XML)

df = xmlInternalTreeParse("./Data/ObterDetalhesDeputado.xml")
df_root = xmlRoot(df)
df_children = xmlChildren(df_root)

df_flattened = map_dfr(df_children,  ~.x %>% 
                         xmlToList() %>% 
                         unlist %>% 
                         stack %>% 
                         mutate(ind = as.character(ind),
                                ind = make.unique(ind)) %>% # for duplicate identifiers
                         spread(ind, values))
```

Following Nodes are nested lists. So they will appear as duplicate columns with numbers affixed. You can remove them accordingly.

```
cargosComissoes 2
partidoAtual 3
gabinete 3
historicoLider 4
comissoes 11
```

Comment: tks. This works. I first collect 1000 xml files in a list. Then lapply your flattening scheme above for that list. It takes about 10min to run but works.